# Excel 2010 to display negative numbers for calculated value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

If I use the following formula:

```
=IF((B4-C4)<=0,C4-B4,B4-C4)
```

to calculate two cells and it is a negative,
how can I display it as a negative number?

Comment: It can never be negative because you force the result positive, but you could use conditional formatting based on the original test.

Answer (score 1):

As per your condition

```
If ((a - b) <= 0) Then
    return b - a;
Else
    return a - b;
EndIf
```

it will never give a result less than zero.

```
a=1  b=2  displays 1 (2-1)
a=2  b=1  displays 1 (2-1)
a=1  b=-2 displays 3 (1--2)
a=-2 b=1  displays 3 (1--2)
a=-1 b=2  displays 3 (2--1)
a=2  b-1  displays 3 (3--1)
a=-1 b=-2 displays 1 (-1--2)
a=-2 b=-1 displays 1 (-1--2)
```

So there is no way it will display negative numbers. If you want it to return negative numbers only then change the condition to

```
=IF((B4-C4)<=0;B4-C4;C4-B4)
```